# How to share the same test cases between suites in protractor

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I have some test cases that can be shared between test suites

Lets say suite x and suite y share the same set of test cases (it functions).

i have made a separate .js file that has the shared code which looks something like this.

```
module.exports = function(a,b){
//...
test cases..
//....
}
```

I am trying to use this module in both x and y

this is how x looks

```
var common = require('./module');

describe("description", module(a,b);
```

can this be done? is there any other way?

The common js in my code looks like

```
module.exports = function(a,b) {

beforeAll(function(){
//some code
}
afterAll(function(){
//some code
}

It(‘ads’, function(){
code
}

it(‘ads’, function(){
code
}

it(‘ads’, function(){
code
}


}
```

i want to use this as the function argument for the describe function with passable parameters in two other suites.

Suite1

```
var common = ('./common');
describe('this is a test case', common(a,b);
```

is this possible?

Comment: Write method e.g. `openBrowser(...)` and run this method inside both suits.

Comment: Could you elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't directly run an "it" from another file. However you can run functions, and a function can do everything an "it" can do. For example:

**Helper.js** (This is your function file)

```
export class helper{
  static itFunctionOne(){
    //Test code goes here
  }
  static itFuncitonTwo(){
    //Test code goes here
  }
}
```

And then in your tests
**Test1:**

```
const helper = require('relative/path/to/file/helper.js');
describe('Doing test 1 stuff',function(){
  it('Should run test',function(){
    helper.itFunctionOne();
    helper.itFunctionTwo();
  }
}
```

**Test2:**

```
const helper = require('relative/path/to/file/helper.js');
describe('Doing test 2 stuff',function(){
  it('Should run test',function(){
    helper.itFunctionOne();
    helper.itFunctionTwo();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your inputs i have modified the question and the last part is what my current code looks like. Kindly let me know if my request is possible

Comment: I am also relying on the beforeAll and afterAll functions to log-in and log-out the user. I am unable to pass any arguments through to the helper function

Answer (score 1):

If you have your common.js file similar to...

```
module.exports = function(a,b){
//...
test cases..
//....
}
```

And your test.js file:

```
var common = require('./common'); // <-- note the change

describe("description", common); // <-- you were calling module*
```

This is assuming your common.js exported function is a properly formatted describe function.

You could also export individual test cases like (other.js)...

```
module.exports = {
    testOne: function(something) { return false; },
    testTwo: function(whatever) { return true; }
}
```

And your test...

```
var other = require('./other');

describe("description", function() {
    it('should pass', function() {
        expect(other.testOne()).toEqual(false);
    });
});
```